Error when I try to install pyCGNS to PyCharm (ERROR: No .egg-info directory found in C:\Users\Nolan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-d74ri4in)
I'm trying to install the python package pyCGNS to PyCharm, but it gives the command output:
Collecting pyCGNS==6.2.2
  Using cached pyCGNS-6.2.2.tar.gz (11.6 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'

ERROR: No .egg-info directory found in C:\Users\Nolan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-6w4i84h1

I'm pretty new to Python/coding in general, so I'm not sure how to go about fixing this problem.
See above: cannot install pyCGNS to PyCharm

What is your python version? Please show us the complete error message
